# Find all hyperlinks and add another redirect link within a text

Tags: php, regex

I want to find all hyperlinks in text and adding a link redirect to every link
Example text

```
Hello Visit our website <a href="http://example.com">Here</a>
```

The result I want is

```
Hello Visit our website <a href="https://mywebsite.com?q=http://example.com">Here</a>
```

The code I have tried

```
    $reg_exUrl = "/<a\s[^>]*href=(\\\" ??)([^\\\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>/siU";
$text = 'Hello visit our website <a href="https://example.com">Book</a>';
if(preg_match($reg_exUrl, $text, $url)) {
    echo preg_replace($reg_exUrl, '<a href="http://mywebsite.com?q='.$url[0].'">'.$url[2].'</a>', $text);

} else {
    echo $text;
}
```

So the result of my code is

```
Hello visit our website Book">https://example.com
```

Which in HTML inspect is

```
Hello visit our website <a href="http://mywebsite.com?q=<a href="https://example.com">Book</a>">https://example.com</a>
```

Comment: Looks overcomplicate. Maybe something simple like [`/<a\s[^>]*?\bhref=" *\K(?=http)/i`](https://regex101.com/r/NpWF7G/1) would suffice.

Comment: How simple is, Many thanks, solved!

Answer (score 0):

When there are no other attributes:

```
$string = preg_replace('~<a href="[^"]+">~', '<a href="#">', $string);
```

Otherwise:

```
$string = preg_replace('~<a ([^>]*)href="[^"]+"([^>]*)>~', '<a \\1href="#"\\2>', $string);
```

Demo:

```
php > $string = 'text....<a asd="blub" href="orig-link" title="bla"> Link text </a> other text .....'; 
php > echo preg_replace('~<a ([^>]*)href="[^"]+"([^>]*)>~', '<a \\1href="#"\\2>', $string); text....<a asd="blub" href="#" title="bla"> Link text </a> other text
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = preg_replace_callback('@(<a[^>]+href=")([^"]+)(")@', 'add_track_callback', $text);

function add_track_callback($matches){
    $track_url_base = 'https://mywebsite.com?q=';
    return $matches[1] . $track_url_base . urlencode($matches[2]) . $matches[3];
}
```

Change `$track_url_base` as you need.